# Why we needed slope when we had angles already?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that slope is the tangent of angle of inclination. But are they just two ways of defining the same thing? Or do they have any significant differences regarding what purpose they serve in mathematics? The way angles are defined as arc divided by radius, while slope the height divided by the base, doesn't show much difference. I only have a basic understanding of calculus.

Comment: The "slope of a tangent line" is the simplest instance of a very powerful idea: the derivative. The derivative of a function can be made sense of in a much more general context, in which "angles" might not even make sense. Unfortunately, to truly appreciate this requires knowledge of fairly advanced mathematics, and so I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Have you learned calculus before, wordman soft? It would help if you could edit your question to indicate your background, so that people can pitch an answer at the right level.